# How can I get the value pair of a specific key?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays, json

I'm wanting to get the key value pair for a the specific div, and only the div that I click on. Right now it is logging the values for each div. How can I get only the value for the specific div that I am clicking on? I'm wanting to update during an ajax success, but I'm stumped as to how to update only a certain div. Any ideas as to how I can do this?

```
$('.wrapper').on('click', '.bet-button', function() {
    var self = $(this);
    var gameId = self.attr('gameid');
    var awayVal = $('#' + gameId + ' input[name=betAmountAway]').val();
    var homeVal = $('#' + gameId + ' input[name=betAmountHome]').val();
    var awayId = $('#' + gameId + ' .bet-input-away').data('away-id');
    var homeId = $('#' + gameId + ' .bet-input-home').data('home-id');
    var pointTotals = $('#' + gameId + ' .total-points').val();
    console.log(pointTotals);
    var value = awayVal || homeVal;
    var id, value;




    if (awayVal) {
      id = awayId;
      value = awayVal;
    }
    if (homeVal) {
      id = homeId;
      value = homeVal;
    }

    if (!value) {
        alert('please enter a value!')
    } else {
        $.ajax({
          url: "---------" + userId + "/"+ gameId +"/"+ id +"/"+ value +"",
          type: "get",
        success: function(response) {



            // Makes the inputs inputable again.
            $('.bet-input-home').prop('disabled', false);
            $('.bet-input-away').prop('disabled', false);



            function update(){

                var currentSelection = $('#team-select').val();

                getGames().done(function(results){
                    $.each(results, function (i, gameData){
                        $.each(gameData, function(key, game){
                            var gamesHome = game.home_team_conference;
                            var gamesAway = game.away_team_conference;

                            if(gamesHome == currentSelection || gamesAway == currentSelection){
                                var gameId = game.id;
                                var pointTotal = game.total_points_bet;
                                var gameTime = game.game_time_hour;
                                var gameDate = game.game_time_date;
                                var homeId = game.home_team.id;
                                var awayId = game.away_team.id;
                                var homePoints = game.total_points_bet_on_hometeam;
                                var awayPoints = game.total_points_bet_on_awayteam;
                                var totalPoints = homePoints + awayPoints;

                                // $('#point-total').append(homePoints + awayPoints);

                            }

                        });
                    });
                })
            }
            update();
```

This updates html code that is generated dynamically (or at least it is supposed to)

```
$('.wrapper').append('\
                <div id="'+ gameId +'" class="main-wrapper col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12">\
                <div class="game-cards">\
                <div class="chart-container">\
                <canvas id="'+ homeTeam +'" width="500" height="500"></canvas>\
                </div>\
                <div class="right-info">\
                <h4>' + awayTeam + '<br>' + " @ " + '<br>' + homeTeam +'</h4>\
                <h5 id="time-channel">'+ gameDate +' @ ' + gameTime  + '<br>' + ' On ' + network +'</h5>\
                <div class="total-points-live">\
                <h5>Total Points Bet</h5>\
                <h5 class="total-points" id="point-total">'+ totalPoints +'</h5>\
                <p>'+ awayTeam +'</p>\
                <input class="bet-input-away" data-away-id="'+ awayId +'" data-team-type="'+ awayTeam +'" type="number" pattern="[0-9]*" name="betAmountAway" placeholder="Wager Amount">\
                <p>'+ homeTeam +'</p>\
                <input class="bet-input-home" data-home-id="'+ homeId +'" data-team-type="'+ homeTeam +'" type="number" pattern="[0-9]*" name="betAmountHome" placeholder="Wager Amount">\
                <p class="bet-button" gameid="'+ gameId +'">Click To Place Bet</p>\
                </div>\
                </div>\
                </div>\
                ');
```

Comment: `gameid=""` is an invalid attribute. Use `data-game-id=""` instead. The exact same way you did for `.data('away-id')` so you can get it using `.data("game-id")`

Comment: `if (homeVal) {` is redundant since you have `var value = awayVal || homeVal;`

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan I'm confused, could you explain more?

Comment: *`but I'm stumped as to how to update only a certain div`* is way too broad. Whats DIVs? What's the general idea? Can you clarify in few extra lines?

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan I updated the bottom, the html code is created dynamically.